# How to add constraints to new subview added after button tapped

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm adding Sign In popup view when user click on SignIn button,

I've give constraints to That SingInView.

But it seems doesn't working for me.

Here is my code.

```
viewSignIn!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0) , metrics: nil, views:["view":viewSubSignIn]))
viewSignIn!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0) , metrics: nil, views:["view":viewSubSignIn]))
```

and tried this also.

```
 var constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.viewSignIn!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
 var constY = NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.viewSignIn!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In what way does this not code not work?

Comment: Thank you @RileyAvron, It is not placing the view at correct position.(i.e.in Center)

Comment: Show us the creation of the view. Did you call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`? And which is the view and which is the subview? (Usually `view` is the top level view, in which case these constraints would appear to be backwards.) Also, you say it's not centered: So where is it? Tell us more than "it didn't work." Did you get any error message on the console? Also, you say you want it centered, but your constraints are define to have it overlap entirely, not just center it. Bottom line, please edit your question, adding more information.

Comment: yes I did call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

Comment: Are you sure `viewSubSignIn` is not correct and its subview's aren't just incorrect? Those constraints are really "centering" the view. They are pinning it to all of it's superview's edges (which can often appear to be centering). Like a label would not "centered" using those constraints (as the contents are left aligned). Can you maybe link to an image of what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints are added in your subview, but you don't apply these new constraints in your viewController.
So, try to call this function in your viewController after adding these constraints.

```
[self.view updateConstraints];
```